# Go: Split data into batches to concurrent/parallel update in DB

Tags: go

Given a large slice with data that needs to be updated in the sql-like DB.
Update in one SQL query can be long and lead to problems.

How to split this data into batches to concurrent/parallel update with small queries? For example:

```
UPDATE tablename SET uid=12345 WHERE url IN (...)
```

A small example:

```
type Task struct {
    URL     string
    UID     string
}

type Pool struct {
    numWorkers  int
    tasks       chan Task
    done        chan bool
}

func New(numWorkers int, buffer int) *Pool {
    return &Pool{
        numWorkers: numWorkers,
        tasks:      make(chan Task, buffer),
        done:       make(chan bool),
    }
}


func (p *Pool) Run() {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    for i := 0; i < p.numWorkers; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(i int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            for {
                select {
                case task := <-p.tasks:
                    // execute 
                case <-p.done:
                    close(p.tasks)
                    return
                }

            }
        }(i)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    p.done <- true
}

func (p *Pool) AddTask(urls []string, uid string) {
    for _, url := range urls {
        p.tasks <- Task{URL: url, UID: uid}
    }
}
```

Comment: "Update in one SQL query can be long and lead to problems" What problems?  Is this a question about Go concurrency or db performance optimization?  If your question is about Go, let's take out the question about SQL for now and focus on getting your concurrency working properly.

Comment: @erik258 about Go concurrency. It would be desirable to parallelize queries.

Comment: okay then can you turn your code into a complete reproducible example so we have something to work from?  Maybe something on the go playground?

Comment: Are you sure that your database and database driver support this kind of parallelization? it might be that adding go concurrency here won't be effective.
It might be a better solution to create a queue and buffer the queries so they won't be blocking but keep executing them on one thread/goroutine.

Answer (score 0):

Lets's take a look at this chunk:

```
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    for i := 0; i < p.numWorkers; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(i int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            for {
                select {
                case task := <-p.tasks:
                    // execute 
                case <-p.done:
                    close(p.tasks)
                    return
                }

            }
        }(i)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    p.done <- true
```

You start a bunch of workers.  Each will run until they read from `p.done`.  After the return (`defer`) they will signal `Done` though the wait group.

then you wait for the workers to return.  After they return, you signal `p.done`.

There are 2 problems here.

1. deadlock.  Parent goroutine can't finish `wg.Wait` until the workers read from `p.done`.  The workers won't read from p.done until after they call `wg.Done`.
2. as a mechanism to signal doneness to the workers, you would have to send to `p.done` `p.numWorkers` times.

You don't need `p.done` at all.  Instead, use `close(p.tasks)` to signal to the workers that the channel input is complete, then `wg.Wait` to signal that all tasks are complete.

```
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for  task := range p.tasks {
               // execute 
            }
        }()
```

`close` once you're done enqueueing work...

```
    for _, url := range urls {
        p.tasks <- Task{URL: url, UID: uid}
    }
    close(p.tasks)
```

`wg.Wait` to make sure the workers have completed all work.

```
   wg.Wait()
```